# Bootcamp: setup of Windows 7 (64 bit) hanging at "disk.sys"

Tags: windows-7, mac, 64-bit, boot-camp

I am having trouble getting Windows 7 Professional (64bit) to install on a Macbook Pro (late 2010 model). The installer hangs when loading the setup from disk.

When restarting, I get an option to boot Windows from disk. The installer then starts loading files from disk and suddenly hangs.

Using "Safe Mode" (from the advanced menu), it tells me that the installer hangs when loading "disk.sys".

The installation is made on a fresh Bootcamp partition, the disk uses GPT.

Has anyone seen this before and maybe found a solution?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am facing the exact same issue, trying to install Win7 64bit on a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer my own question: it seems like the issue is somehow related to not using a superdrive, but a different external drive. (I have a modded Macbook Pro, with a HDD instead of the superdrive).

In the end, I did something really weird: you can setup a VMWare Box that is backed by a physical partition. So I installed Windows in the Virtual Machine up until it tried to restart  and then restarted the macbook and booted from the half-installed partition. Worked flawlessly.

There is a guide on how to do that somewhere on the internet, but I cannot find it at the moment.